# Determine last line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I'm wondering how I can determine when I am on the last line of a file that I reading in. My code looks like

```
File.open(file_name).each do |line|
    if(someway_to_determine_last_line)
end
```

I noticed that there is a file.eof? method, but how would I call the method as the file is being read? Thanks!

Comment: A bunch of stuff is going on. I need to know when the line that I am on is the last line or last non-empty line of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're iterating the file with `each`, then the last line will be passed to the block *after* the end-of-file is reached, because the last line is, by definition, the line ending with EOF.

So just call `file.eof?` in the block.

If you'd like to determine if it's the last *non-empty* line in the file, you'd have to implement some kind of readahead.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you need to do with this "last non-empty line", you might be able to do something like this:

```
last_line = nil
File.open(file_name).each do |line|
    last_line = line if(!line.chomp.empty?)
    # Do all sorts of other things
end
if(last_line)
    # Do things with the last non-empty line.
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Secret sauce is `.to_a`

```
lines = File.open(filename).to_a
```

Get the first line:

```
puts lines.first
```

Get the last line:

```
puts lines.last
```

Get the *n* line of a file:

```
puts lines.at(5)
```

Get the count of lines:

```
puts lines.count
```

Comment: This will load the whole file in memory, so it's not a good option for huge files.

Answer (score 1):

`fd.eof?` works, but just for fun, here's a generic solution that works with any kind of enumerators (Ruby 1.9):

```
class Enumerator
  def +(other)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      each { |e| yielder << e }
      other.each { |e| yielder << e }
    end
  end

  def with_last
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      (self + [:some_flag_here]).each_cons(2) do |a, b|
        yielder << [a, b == :some_flag_here]
      end
    end
  end
end

# a.txt is a file containing "1\n2\n3\n"
open("a.txt").lines.with_last.each do |line, is_last|
  p [line, is_last]
end
```

Which outputs:

```
["1\n", false]
["2\n", false]
["3\n", true]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your file and use the readline method:

To simply manipulate last line of file do the following:

```
f = File.open('example.txt').readlines
f.each do |readline|
  if readline[f.last]
    puts "LAST LINE, do something to it"
  else
    puts "#{readline} "
  end
end
```

Line 1 reads the file in as an array of lines

Line 2 uses that object and iterates over each of them

Line 3 tests if the current line matches the last line

Line 4 acts if it's a match

Line 5 & 6 handle behavior for non-matching circumstance